# How to duplicate embedded SVG DOM in HTML using Closure library?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-closure-library

I want to duplicate an embedded SVG in HTML, re-define it's IDs inside.

For example, there is a HTML file like

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="svgs">
    </div>

    <!-- Template -->
    <div style="display:none;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="181" height="59" id="type0svg">
        <g style="display:inline" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <text id="ph1" x="23.6" y="51.7">ph1</text>
          <text id="ph2" x="105.1" y="51">ph2</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and data `[{ph1:'placeholder1',ph2:'placeholder2'},{ph1:'apple',ph2:'orange'}]`. I want to generate a DOM like ...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="svgs">
      <!-- {ph1:'placeholder1',ph2:'placeholder2'} -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="181" height="59" id="type0svg1">
        <g style="display:inline" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <text id="ph1_1" x="23.6" y="51.7">placeholder1</text>
          <text id="ph2_1" x="105.1" y="51">placeholder2</text>
        </g>
      </svg>

      <!-- {ph1:'apple',ph2:'orange'} -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="181" height="59" id="type0svg2">
        <g style="display:inline" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <text id="ph1_2" x="23.6" y="51.7">apple</text>
          <text id="ph2_2" x="105.1" y="51">orange</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <!-- Template -->
    <div style="display:none;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="181" height="59" id="type0svg">
        <g style="display:inline" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <text id="ph1" x="23.6" y="51.7">ph1</text>
          <text id="ph2" x="105.1" y="51">ph2</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that all IDs under copied DOM has been re-defined from 'blahblah' to 'blahblah_1' and 'blahblah_2'.

How can this be done smartly using Google closure library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

**Duplication of node**. Use the standard DOM method [`Node.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) to create deep clones of a node.

**Redefinition of IDs**. The `goog.ui.Component` framework uses [`goog.ui.IdGenerator`](https://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_IdGenerator.html) extensively to generate unique IDs of the form `<ID>:<increment>` (there's another implementation in [`goog.events.getUniqueId`](https://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_events_events.js.html#goog.events.getUniqueId) if you don't mind the events baggage). With the same underlying idea you can create your own ID generator.

**Tree walking**. The `goog.dom` namespace has a number of node iterators that can be reliably used to arrive at elements whose IDs must be changed.

I set up a [**JSBin example**](http://jsbin.com/sijed/10/edit) that creates as many clones as replacement sets are specified in the data array, uniquifies IDs, and appends the clones to `#svgs`.

If DOM methods are undesirable, Closure Library also provides an html SAX parser ([`goog.string.html.HtmlParser`](https://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_string_html_HtmlParser.html) under "third-party") which can serve as the base of a DOM-less approach (*note:* the parser doesn't support SVG elements out of the box).